# When using LINQ to Entities, is there a better method than casting to list in order to use unsupported code/extensions?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I find myself needing to do things like this frequently, and I'm just curious if there is a better way.

Suppose I have a class that holds a snapshot of some data:

```
private List<Person> _people;
```

In some method I populate that list from a LINQ query using Entity Framework, and perhaps I need to, for example, run a custom IEqualityComparer on it.  Since this isn't supported in LINQ to entities, I end up with something like this:

```
_people = db.People.Where(...)
    .ToList()
    .Distinct(new MyCustomComparer())
    .ToList();
```

Another example might be using an extension method, which also is not supported in LINQ to entities:

```
_people = db.People.Where(...)
    .ToList()
    .Select(_ => new { Age = _.DOB.MyExtensionMethod() })
    .ToList();
```

In order to use either of these I have to cast the database entities into regular memory objects with the first ToList(),  and then since I ultimately want a list anyway, I have a final cast ToList() at the end.  This seems inefficient to me, and I'm wondering if there's a better pattern for these types of situations?

Comment: Ideally you should try and convert your `MyCustomComparer` to a `linq-to-entities` friendly query. Otherwise you will be loading the entire table into memory every time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `AsEnumerable()`:

```
_people = db.People.Where(...)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Distinct(new MyCustomComparer())
    .ToList();
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
IEnumerable<Person> _people = db.People.Where(...);
_people = _people.Distinct(new MyCustomComparer()).ToList();
```

This is not much of an improvement, but at least it doesn't create another `List<T>` and is better expressing that you want to switch to the realm of `IEnumerable<T>` (in-memory).

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb335435(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: I had actually read that MSDN page and I guess I misunderstood, I thought it was simply changing the return interface and that the query would still occur in the underlying SQL provider.  Since that doesn't appear to be the case, I would assume it must be pushing those entities into memory, in which case is this any more efficient?  I do agree it's more readable code.

Comment: @amnesia, `AsEnumerable()` doesn't "push those entities into memory". Since Linq uses deferred execution, the query will be executed only once, and that would be during the `ToList()` call. The `AsEnumerable()` is only making sure that further Linq method calls (like `Distinct`) will be intercepted by `Enumerable.Distinct` and not by `Queryable.Distinct` (and it does so by returning `IEnumerable<T>`, hence breaking the `IQueryable<T>` chain).

Comment: Ahh, I see now. Thanks, that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @amnesia, Once last bit: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,825